# Cannot connect to iTunes Store for purchase process?

Tags: iphone, ios7

## My Code

```
 #define kMyFeatureIdentifier @"com.yourcompany.FussballQuiz"
 - (void) initializeStore
 {
        SKProductsRequest *request= [[SKProductsRequest alloc]
                             initWithProductIdentifiers:
                             [NSSet setWithObject: kMyFeatureIdentifier]];
        request.delegate = self;
        [request start];
 }
 -(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:  (SKProductsResponse *)response
 {

}
- (void) request:(SKRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
   NSLog(@"Failed to connect with error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

## output

Failed to connect with error: Cannot connect to iTunes Store
..
why not call didReceiveResponse in iphone?

Comment: How are you testing this ? Simulator or device ? You can only test purhcases on Devices now

Comment: simulator use for testing

Comment: but, sir testing code are work correctly with out real device.

Comment: You can't test in app purchase code on simulator. See my answer below:

Comment: i try this code then accept your ans..ok sir

Answer (score 2):

You can only test purchases using a real device. Simulator will always return an error. Be sure to sign out of an iTunes store account on the device before hand and use a sandbox user.

EDIT:

See this for more guidance:

https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/